# core-ajax is sending requests with different session id every time

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, polymer

I am using core-ajax to send requests to my NodeJS backend. But the session ID of the requests differ every time.

How do I configure so that frontend can send request with the same session ID?

Note that my frontend and backend are hosted on different servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) module on your node application, and setup your front-end to send the request with `withCredentials` set to true.